# How to install patch from github for python library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, patch

I get an error after running python code.
The following patch from github is supposed to fix the error, as it is library based.

How to install this patch to my computer ?

https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commit/8864b46849b031a3013764d03e167222963c0f5d

Comment: How did you install python-igraph? Can you find the file `igraph/drawing/__init__.py`?

Comment: @Orto with conda install or with pip (using ubuntu).
I can find the file. I hoped that there is a simpler way by copying repository or something.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484585/6309